# CISCO Catalyst switch API

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco catalyst switch and there is a task to code some web gate which will allow billing to control ports in switch, gather different statistics, etc.
What is the modern way to achieve that? Earlier with a supermicro switch I just wrote a PHP script which did a `shell_exec` passing commands to `netcat` which connected to the switch. I don't think this the best way to do that so I am asking for help.

Maybe there are some libraries for that? For Perl I saw a library called [Net::Appliance::Session](http://search.cpan.org/~oliver/Net-Appliance-Session-4.142720/lib/Net/Appliance/Session.pm) and it looks really good as I see, but I am not that good in Perl so I am looking for something PHP/Ppython based.

**Update**
What I found so far for Python is [Trigger](https://trigger.readthedocs.org) and [Exscript](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/wiki). Looks pretty nice for my simple port on/off and speed change tasks:

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2

account = read_login()              
conn = SSH2()                       
conn.connect('14.45.43.5')     
conn.login(account)                 
conn.execute('conf t')              
print conn.response
conn.send('exit\r')           
conn.close()
```

But I still think I am going to have some headache parsing different status reports, so maybe I need to do that using something different or split stats gathering and operation functionality. Use SNMP for stats for example.

Comment: Have a good, hard look at SNMP. This is still a good way to gather that kind of data from a switch.

Comment: I need not only to gather, but to control as well. Like disable port, change port's speed, etc.

Comment: Look at Cisco's own CiscoWorks software

Comment: Documentation on it so awful ... I haven't even found concrete CLI examples. 
Besides i do not see the point of it. It's a standalone solution and i see how to communicate with it from code.

Comment: You might try the [clogin](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/man/clogin.1.html) expect script (part of [RANCID](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/))

Comment: You may wish to look at SNMP for writing, too.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170644/how-can-i-enable-disable-ports-in-cisco-catalyst-2960-with-c for an example.

Comment: Sorry guys, cannot comment yet, but i wanted to add my 2 here. Have you looked at using just the Paramiko SSH library exclusively in Python instead? Its expect-like, but a little different. Does what you want. I don't want to turn this into a Paramiko vs. Expect argument either. Everyone has their favorite right :-)

Comment: I did. I looked both into Paramiko and Expect. For my tasks they kind of the same. But i wanted to find something more Cisco oriented. I thought that at least somebody once upon a time wrote a small library for doing simple tasks with cisco equipment. And it seems there isn't. Either quite big overloaded libraries or something Paramiko like ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `PySNMP`. It wasn't clear that SNMP v3 has pretty encryption and it also allows not only to gather data but also manipulate the device.